# PayPal is showing only the payment options of some of the enable-funding values

Tags: reactjs, paypal

I have this code set up for dynamically adding the script into the body of my react website. I'm using an npm package called react-paypal-buttons-v2

```
const script = document.createElement('script');
script.type = 'text/javascript';
script.src = `https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=${clientId}&currency=USD&enable-funding=credit,paylater,venmo,bancontact,blik,eps,giropay,ideal,mercadopago,mybank,p24,sepa,sofort`;
script.async = true;

script.onload = () => {
    setSdkReady(true);
};

document.body.appendChild(script);
```

Code for rendering buttons -

```
import { PayPalButton } from 'react-paypal-button-v2'
<PayPalButton amount={order.totalPrice} onSuccess={sucessPaymentHandler} />
```

Everything is working fine except PayPal is only showing some of the payment methods (paypal credit, venmo and a few other buttons are not being shown)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Payment methods only show up when the buyer [is eligible](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/reference/customize-sdk/#enable-funding), this is the normal and expected behavior.

You won't see both paylater and credit, you won't see giropay outside Germany, you won't see mercadopago outside south america, etc.

To test different locations in sandbox mode, use `&buyer-country=XX`. This only works for sandbox.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error too.

Idk if me changing `Personal` to `Business` account worked or me using `enableFunding: "paypal"` instead of `enableFunding: "paypal.FUNDING.PAYPAL"` worked or both had an effect but once I changed both of these things, I solved it.

One thing I can confirm is that `enableFunding: "paypal.FUNDING.PAYPAL"` doesn't work as I tried it when refreshing. At least, in React.js/Next.js even though the docs still show it.

But yeah, if you are facing an error, try using a `Business` account & use `enableFunding: "paypal"` instead to see if it works. Also, only some countries support `paylater`, `venmo` so you can safely remove it if an option isn't shown to you.